# What are some examples of nice animated clips for introducing the notion of derivation and integration in calculus?

Tags: calculus

> What are some examples of nice animated clips for introducing the notion of derivation and integration in calculus?

I would like to know what are some examples of nice animated clips that could help people learning the notions of derivation and integration, say by describing a particular physical phenomena.

Comment: I think Wikipedia might have a few?

Comment: [LucasVB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User%3aLucasVB/Gallery) has a couple of nice ones on Riemann integrals.

Comment: [$[1]$](http://www.thecalculuspage.com/images/animationgraphicderivativeforpp.gif), [$[2]$](http://www.peterstone.name/Maplepgs/images/Deriv_graph_anim.gif), and [$[3]$](http://www.jonahgreenthal.com/calculus/lessons/mv/1.2/tansec.gif) are a couple of derivative animations I found pretty quickly from Google Images.

Comment: http://mathinsight.org/

Comment: Differentiation, even.